# Is there a tag for various around-the-table issues?

Tags: support, tags

I found that there is are not many tags that relate to around the table issues that do not directly relate to the game. I asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/is-there-good-ways-of-distributing-pregen-characters), but found myself at disadvantage when choosing appropriate tags. Is there a tag or multiple tags that would be used for issues around the table that are related to things like:

- location, ambience, lighting, furniture,
- refreshments, spirits, snacks,
- breaks, distractions, "background" noise
- techniques for setting up the game in an efficient manner,
- distributing props, handouts
- dealing with conflicts over metagame and pre-game or post-game discussions

I have found the following tags, but they only partially relate to the above: 
[social](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social)
[group-dynamics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-dynamics)

Answer (score 3):

For preparation, doppelgreener's suggestions of [props](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/props) and [gm-preparation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-preparation) are good.

For social stuff, we have [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm) and particularly [new-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-players) for lack of experience, and [problem-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-gm) and [problem-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-players) for problematic interaction at the table. [metagaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagaming) and [powerplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerplaying) could be appropriate for excess strategy discussions at the table (and [optimization](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) when it's not in excess).

For keeping the game fluent, there's [pacing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacing), but that seems to be a very unused tag and there are a lot of questions that have neglected tagging it.

For background music, there's [music](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) but it seems to be very scarcely used too.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find one myself, and none comes to mind. We do have [props](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/props), but not stuff for ambience and so on, breaks and snacks, and etc. We have [gm-preparation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-preparation) too, but that's pre-game stuff.

What you've described is pretty broad though (especially when you throw in metagame conflicts and discussions), and might not be well served by *just one tag* for the whole lot.

Comment: As in my question, "is there a tag or multiple tags..." Having a bunch of tags that cover these would be just as useful for me.